# Layouts - MATCH_PARENT hides elements

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm preparing layout for list of countries shown in categories. I have problem formatting my layout. I want category titles (bigger ones) to be "100% width", so far they are WRAP_CONTENT formatted (blue colour is for testing purposes):

[image: Debug view]

I used the following code:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
table.setPadding(24, 14, 24, 24);
table.setStretchAllColumns(true);  
table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

// ...

TableRow titleRow = new TableRow(this);
titleRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
titleRow.setPadding(0, 18, 0, 8);
titleRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText("TEST TITLE");  //title.setText(currentContinent); 
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
title.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 8);

titleRow.addView(title);
table.addView(titleRow, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I changed last part of code to make TextView filling parent (TableRow):

```
titleRow.addView(title, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
table.addView(titleRow, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But then my TextView dissapears!

[Debug view http://www.wysyper.pl/u/4417tahfcvnb.jpeg](http://www.wysyper.pl/u/4417tahfcvnb.jpeg)

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trust that you have a good reason not to use XML layouts for this, which should make your life a lot less code-filled and eliminate some potential bugs.

Have you tried it using instances of the proper `LayoutParams` subclass for your parent views?  Each view added to a `TableLayout` should use instances of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. Likewise `TableRow` expects instances of `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

If that doesn't fix it, I recommend building the layout in XML instead of code.